# Form value encoding in PHP

Tags: html

I would like to send out a value in a PHP form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Car">
```

And I would like to specify the value is in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)...

What steps do I have to do?

Comment: chinese word encoding...

Comment: if you set <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> in header, doesn`t it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the header of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This will tell the browser to submit the characters in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to put this in your [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Document_structure_elements)-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code after the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score -2):

`<?= utf8_encode($the_var) ?>` should achieve what you need.

Comment: Off-topic but shorthand tags are considered bad practice mostly because of portability.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that. It was more to demonstrate usage of the function ^^